# Inject pure Java / Obj-C code in NativeScript App

Tags: mobile, nativescript

I'm currently developing an App for Android / iOS, and now i'm at the stage to let my users interact with Facebook, and especially send private message to their friends.

Facebook implement a SDK for that, for iOS:

```
FBSDKSendButton *button = [[FBSDKSendButton alloc] init];
button.shareContent = content; 
[self.view addSubview:button];
```

And for android:

```
SendButton sendButton = (SendButton)findViewById(R.id.fb_send_button);
sendButton.setShareContent(shareContent);
sendButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() { ... });
```

But i'm unsure if i can actually use those pieces of code with NativeScript.
Does anyone have any experience with facebook send button and NativeScript or at least could shed a light on whether its possible or not.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

There is something similar done in [this NativeScript plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-facebook-login). It provides Facebook login functionality but I believe that it would be fairly easy to make it fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I asked a similar question last week and was able to get use the addSubview call to work like this:

```
var mainView = args.object.getViewById('main-view');
mainView.ios.addSubview(publisher.view);
```

My XML looks like:

```
<Page loaded="pageLoaded">
 <StackLayout id="main-view">
 </StackLayout>
</Page>
```

You'll need an ID on the view you created in your XML, then in the code-behind file in your function, use the `args.object.getViewById('yourViewID');` to create a variable and then call `viewVariable.ios.addSubview('view-you-want-to-add');`.

In my case my framework's `publisher` object is what I passed to the `.ios.addSubview()` call.

Full code-behind file as well:

```
var vmModule = require("./main-view-model");

// moving OpenTok out of the plugin and into code base for dev.
// Will move into a plugin after
var OpenTok = {
    createSession: function(options) {
        var apiKey = 'private';
        var sessionID = 'private';
        var delegate = this;

        // Framework Method
        var session = OTSession.alloc().init();
        return session.initWithApiKeySessionIdDelegate(apiKey, sessionID, delegate);
      },
      createPublisher: function() {
        // Framework Method
        var publisher = OTPublisher.alloc().init();

        return publisher;
      }
};

function pageLoaded(args) {
    var page = args.object;
    var mainView = args.object.getViewById('main-view');
    var token = "private";
    var error = new interop.Reference();
    page.bindingContext = vmModule.mainViewModel;

    var session = OpenTok.createSession();
    // Framework Method
    session.connectWithTokenError(token, error);

    var publisher = OpenTok.createPublisher();
    // Framework Method
    publisher.initWithDelegate(publisher);
    // Native iOS Method
    mainView.ios.addSubview(publisher.view);

    var checkConnectionStatus = setInterval(function(){
      if ( session.sessionConnectionStatus == 1 ) {
          console.log('clear interval');
          clearInterval(checkConnectionStatus);
          // Framework Method
          session.publishError(publisher, null);
      }
    }, 1000);

}

exports.pageLoaded = pageLoaded;
```

This is my question that might also provide more insight if you're still stuck: [Nativescript addSubview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36228043/nativescript-addsubview/36237652#36237652)