# Nativescript addSubview

Tags: nativescript

I'm trying to implement the OpenTok SDK into Nativescript and I've run into an issue that I can't seem to wrap my head around.

Per their documentation (https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/publish-stream/ios/#create_publisher) once you create a publisher object you call:

```
[self.view addSubview:publisher.view];
```

I can't figure out how I would tie this into Nativescript, if it's even possible.

My first thought is that I would want a UIView or View element on my page in the XML, then I would call `.addView(publisher.view);` on that element.

There is a similar question here ([Inject pure Java / Obj-C code in NativeScript App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36007079/inject-pure-java-obj-c-code-in-nativescript-app)) but nothing came of it, the one answer does't provide much help.

I cloned one of OpenTok's sample projects and added their implementation of this call into a gist here: https://gist.github.com/bondydaa/2db355ed45b7e50e4071

You can see at [line 117](https://gist.github.com/bondydaa/2db355ed45b7e50e4071#file-viewcontroller-m-L117) how they implemented this call. This code raises another question for me in that I'm not sure where `_publisherView` comes from.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Nativescript you can try calling the 'ios' property of the container you are trying to add the component to. This will return the native object.

For example if you have a StackLayout, you can:

```
var stackLayout = args.object.getViewById("theIdOfTheStackLayout");
stackLayout.ios.addSubview(publisher.view);
```